# Which process is better to shows a loading page in android?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, httpconnection

i need a loading process to wait the http response querys to my server, which method is better to solve it?

I'm trying with AsyncTask but not works well, my process to recover data is: first i make HttpsURLConnection and i parse all xml files, then i save it in a List, this process can wait 5-10s... I don't know if this process it's correct inside doInBackground()

This is my code but AsyncTask status always was RUNNING..

Thanks

```
class GetTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Integer> {
Context context;
private ApiConnection xml_parse = new ApiConnection();
ProgressDialog  mDialog;
private List<Orders> orders;

public GetTask (Context context){
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    mDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    mDialog.setMessage("Cargando datos...");
    mDialog.show();
}

@Override

protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {
    int count = params.length;
     orders = new ArrayList<Orders>();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

        try {
            orders = xml_parse.tester_orders(params[0]);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Escape early if cancel() is called
        if (isCancelled()) break;
    }
    return count;
}

protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
    mDialog.dismiss();
}

public List<Orders> getOrders(){
    return orders;
}
```

Activity

```
String order_url = "myurlquery";
   GetTask XX = new GetTask(this);
    XX.execute(order_url);
...
if(XX.getStatus().toString() =="FINISHED") {
List<Order> orders = XX.getOrders();
//Print List to ListvView..
}
```

Comment: Where's the HttpUrlConnection located? I mean you mentioned it and it's not in the code above.

Comment: Sure, HttpUrlConnection is in other class, but It works well when used in activities. Inside code is this metoth "xml_parse.tester_orders(String url)"

Comment: Ok, and what exactly happens when you try to run this code? You said it doesn't run correctly? Can you describe a bit more?

Comment: I need a loading page/dialog while i'll download data from querys, and i don't know if the correct process is async task or other one. I have only tried the method async task but always remains in running state, and this is the code.